# i am getting an error message while importing numpy package in windows platform?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>      import numpy as np
>   ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

I have tried to install with `pip` command but in vain. i am using python 3.4.1 version.

Comment: What happens if you do `pip install numpy` Is it installed correctly? Error?

Comment: thanks god. numpy installed. i go to c:\\python34\Scripts in the command prompt, then typed pip install numpy. it was done. thank you  FJSevilla for giving a hint.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows use this from anywhere in the command prompt

```
python -m pip install numpy
```